# USERELATIONSHIP together with FILTER in CALCULATE

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have a dax formula which counts rows based on dates:

```
Avsluttet = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET),USERELATIONSHIP(Dato[Opprettet dato], TICKET[closed_at]))
```

But the column closed_at cointans "null" data that I want to exclude. How do I implement filter in the code above, so it only count rows containing dates?

[image]

I have to keep "null data" in this column because it is connected to another column in the same dataset.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Avsluttet = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET),NOT(ISBLANK('Table'[closed_at])), USERELATIONSHIP(Dato[Opprettet dato], TICKET[closed_at]))
```

Just add a comma and your filter condition to calculate.